# angularjs routing visualstudio

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am learning angularjs using Visual Studio Community 2015. Everything was working fine until I got to routing. I don't know how to work with the server side requirements to test my code with routes and the # in the URL.

When I debug, I get the links but no HTML snippets from adding ngview. I suspect I have to do something to make the server recognize the # in the URL, but after days of reading/searching, no luck (I have read about changing web.config or adding some C# code, but none of these worked for me).

My questions:

- Given the code below, do I have an Angularjs problem?
- What do I have to do to make the server on Community 2015 recognize the # in the URLs?
- What is the best way to debug this? Now, I just get a blank page, no error messages, and none of the links work; ng-view is not displaying the html snippets as expected.

In Community 2015, I started new project with Visual C#>>Web>>asp.net app>>empty template.

Here is my code for Routes:
**ngview in index.html**

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div ng-view></div>
```

**load ngRoute library**

```
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/instructionsController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/faqController.js"></script>
```

**import ngRoute module in app.js**

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
         angular.module('VideoOnTheMove', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])       
    })();
```

**Route.js**

```
    angular.module('VideoOnTheMove')
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/pages/home/index.html'
    })

    .when('/overview', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/pages/overview/index.html'
    })

    .when('/instructions', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/pages/instructions/index.html',
        controller: 'instructionController',
        controllerAs: 'instructionsCtrl'
    })

    .when('/faq', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/pages/faq/index.html',
        controller: 'instructionsController',
        controllerAs: 'faqCtrl'
    })

    .when('/checklist', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/pages/checklist/index.html'
    })

    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: 'home'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Are you bootstrapping the angular app, so using an ng-app directive on the root element in index.html such as the body element?

Comment: Yes, I added that to the html element such as: <html lang="en" ng-app="VideoOnTheMove">

Comment: Remove your last when config and in your otherwise redirect to '/home'. I would suggest looking at the angular ui-router module.

Comment: I can see how the last .when is redundant, so I followed your suggestions. However, I still have the same problem of ng-view not appearing.

Comment: Ok, are you seeing requests in the browser for your scripts and the home template which should be being requested as is your default route

Comment: In Chrome dev tools, I get the error of "failure to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)"

Comment: I tried to put in the path in url as "http://localhost:57834/index.html/#/home" and I get the 404 error with that, also. Is it something to do with something or some code I should have on server side?

Comment: Go to just http://localhost:57834 dont add anything else after, does that give you anything different? Also, does your web server know to serve index.html as a default document, I see you are using Visual Studio, are you hosting under IIS?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio, so I think I must be hosting under IIS. When I just say localhost:57834, I get the same thing (nothing in ng-view area) and no errors in DevTools. I define ng-app on <html> tag, but I don't have a ng-controller on this page; could that be a problem? If so, what should the controller here do?

Comment: Just a thought, you said you are using ng-app on the html element in index, try using it in the body tag instead. I have never seen it used on the html tag. Also in the network tab in chrome check your scripts are actually being loaded in as expected.

Comment: I moved the ng-app to body tag (I am taking a course from CodeSchool and they said to put it on html tag). Still no luck. It does look like my scripts are loading as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller scripts should appear before route config script

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/instructionsController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/faqController.js"></script>

<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
```